# How do you map the thread context when integrating a WCF service and the service bus

Tags: wcf, servicebus, threadcontext

I'm building an azure application with a windows client, a wcf service and a worker role on azure that handles a lot of back ground processing. In some cases I need the wcf service to hand over a task to the back ground process (via a queue) and send a reply back when the worker role indicates that the task is complete.

The current plan is to use service bus messaging to communicate beween the web and worker roles (as suggested by the AzureCAT team). The question is when the worker role responds with the result (by sending  amessage on the service bus), how do I pass that onto the correct wcf thread context that will send the reply back to the calling client? (I will be using topics to ensure the message gets to the appropriate web role instance).